# Performance of nested select and DISTINCT/ORDER

Tags: sql, sql-server

My original query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Member.Id,
Member.Email,
Booking.ItemId
FROM Member WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN Booking WITH(NOLOCK) ON Member.Id = Booking.CustomerId
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Booking.BookingDate, GETUTCDATE()) > 1
```

I tried to order the result by Booking.BookingDate, and added the Booking.BookingDate related information as a new column in the returned result:

So, the new query will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
Member.Id,
Member.Email,
Booking.ItemId,
Booking.BookingDate
FROM Member WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN Booking WITH(NOLOCK) ON Member.Id = Booking.CustomerId
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, Booking.BookingDate, GETUTCDATE()) > 2   
) a
Order by BookingDate
```

I use SSMS's execution plan to compare these two queries, and they look the same.
   Is there any way I can make sure my rewriting won't make performance slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery (although that doesn't affect performance).  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.Id, m.Email, b.ItemId, b.BookingDate
FROM Member m JOIN
     Booking b
     ON m.Id = b.CustomerId
WHERE b.BookingDate > DATEADD(day, 1, GETUTCDATE())
ORDER BY BookingDate;
```

I really doubt you need the `SELECT DISTINCT`, because duplicates seem unlikely.  Notice that the table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.